# Understanding the createServer arguments in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry for the rather un constructive question:
I was watching a tutorial on creating a web server in node.js and i did not understand the meaning of the arguments "response" and "request", so what do they mean exactly ?

I have been looking for answers in the documentation but i was still confused because i am new to node.js.

Thanks for any help and apologies for this question being quite vague.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a HTTP server, the Node thread loops and listens on a port, for incoming HTTP requests.

So, for example server listens at `0.0.0.0:8080` and you open a web browser, type in `http://0.0.0.0:8080`, the browser sends a HTTP request to node server.

All the data related to this request is written to the `request` object, like calling IP address, HTTP headers, url and its parameters etc etc.

Also, Node provides you a `response` object to write into. You can write some string to it and end it. This is sent back to the browser as a result.

To use an analogy: `request` object is like a received letter, and `response` object is like a blank piece of paper to write on, which will be sent back.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request), `request` is a representation of the HTTP Request made by the client. It is an instance of [`http.IncomingMessage`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage), and contains properties such as the URL requested, HTTP version, query params etc.

The `response` is an instance of [`http.ServerResponse`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) and represents the response of the server to the clients request. You set response headers, response statuses and the response message via properties of this object.